# Include Wordpress header in another CakePHP subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, cakephp

Good morning,

For some time, I try to include Wordpress theme in my CakePHP application in a different folder than Wordpress (Wordpress is in ROOT and my CakePHP application is in the PLATFORM file)

However, I added the snippet of code offered by Wordpress wordpress theme for use in a page and I inserted in the file "Layout -> Defaut.ctp" of my application but nothing works ...

```
    <?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('Salient', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<?php
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Could someone tell me if it is possible to integrate its wordpress theme in a CakePHP application.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to integrate a WordPress theme in a CakePHP application, due to the nature of the way wordpress themes are built. You could take the styles.css and move it over, and some of your styles might line up, but by and large the WordPress generated code and the CakePHP generated code will not line up. I would recommend installing WordPress as a subdirectory (blog.yoursite.com) and linking to it as the best way to go about integrating the two.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many articles that could integrate Wordpress inserting in / app / webroot, but I have not seen anything to an external file without being in / app / webroot / ...